# Word VBA Insert Image with Specific Height and Fixed Aspect Ratio

Tags: vba, image, ms-word

I have an image C\VER\Image.png

It needs to be pasted over a selected text (inline) in Word 2007 with a specific height (constraining the image proportions or ratio).

Here is what I have:

```
Dim dutPic As Word.InlineShape

Set dutPic = Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(fileName:=imagePath, _
LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)

dutPic.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
dutPic.Height = 170
```

The height is changed but the width does not follow.

Comment: `pic.LockAspectRatio = True` works for me (Word 2010). What is this  `msoTrue`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the workaround:

```
Dim dutPic As Word.InlineShape
Dim oH As Long, oW As Long 'Original Dimensions of the image
Dim nW As Double, aspect As Double

Set dutPic = Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(fileName:=imagePath, _
  LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)

oW = dutPic.Width
oH = dutPic.Height
aspect = oW / oH 'aspect ratio
nW = aspect * 170 'new width

dutPic.Height = 170 'Desired height
dutPic.Width = nW
```

Calculate the aspect ratio yourself.

Comment: Height and Width are measured in points. There are 72.27 points in 1 inch.